# How to use multiple where between for date in same column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, between

I need a two different values of same column but between different date ranges,this is what i am doing

```
   SELECT `sales-store-id`,
((SUM (`gen-acute-sales-after-returns`) AS `totalGenericSales` ,
(SUM(`eth-acute-sales-after-returns`) AS `totalEthicalSales`, 
SUM(`sales-after-returns`) AS `totalSales` WHERE `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-12') 
AND
  ((SUM (`gen-acute-sales-after-returns`)) AS `totalGenericSalesPM` ,
(SUM(`eth-acute-sales-after-returns`)) AS `totalEthicalSalesPM`,
 SUM(`sales-after-returns`) AS `totalSalesPM` 
FROM `sales` WHERE `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-12') 
GROUP BY`sales-store-id`
```

it was working when for single date range but after adding multiple date range it is giving syntax error

Comment: Including '-' in table/column identifiers is a catastrophically bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using conditional aggregation

```
SELECT `sales-store-id`,
SUM (case when `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-12' then `gen-acute-sales-after-returns` end) AS `totalGenericSales` ,
SUM(case when `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-12' then `eth-acute-sales-after-returns` end) AS `totalEthicalSales`, 
SUM(case when `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-12' then `sales-after-returns` end) AS `totalSales`,  
SUM (case when `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-12' then `gen-acute-sales-after-returns` end ) AS `totalGenericSalesPM` ,
SUM(case when `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-12' then `eth-acute-sales-after-returns` end) AS `totalEthicalSalesPM`,
SUM(case when `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-12' then `sales-after-returns` end) AS `totalSalesPM` 
FROM `sales` 
GROUP BY`sales-store-id`
```

Comment: Can we use multiple column in single case like this "SUM (case when `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-12' then `gen-acute-sales-after-returns`, `eth-acute-sales-after-returns`end) AS `totalGenericSales`"

Comment: this is not working actually what am i missing here?

Comment: what is your expected output @Saurabh

Comment: to get a value of sum of two different column in in single case

Comment: it would be great if you provide your sample data and expected output in table format in your question - you know it's much easy to understand @Saurabh

Comment: @Saurabh, do you want to mean you need sum of two condition value in single column?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping on a sub-query with a UNION ALL for the different date ranges could work for this.

```
SELECT `sales-store-id`,
SUM(GenericSales) AS TotalGenericSales,
SUM(EthicalSales) AS TotalEthicalSales,
SUM(Sales) AS TotalSales,
SUM(GenericSalesPM) AS TotalGenericSalesPM,
SUM(EthicalSalesPM) AS TotalEthicalSalesPM,
SUM(SalesPM) AS TotalSalesPM
FROM
(
  SELECT `sales-store-id`,
  `gen-acute-sales-after-returns` AS GenericSales,
  `eth-acute-sales-after-returns` AS EthicalSales, 
  `sales-after-returns` AS Sales,
  0.0 AS GenericSalesPM, 
  0.0 AS EthicalSalesPM, 
  0.0 AS SalesPM
  FROM `sales` 
  WHERE `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-12' 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT `sales-store-id`, 0, 0, 0,
  `gen-acute-sales-after-returns`,
  `eth-acute-sales-after-returns`,
  `sales-after-returns` 
  FROM `sales`
  WHERE `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-12'
) q
GROUP BY `sales-store-id`
```